# VSC highlighted lint errors

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, highlight, static-analysis

I´m using flake 8 to lint my Python code. On the editor's mini map (right panel of editor) any error/warning is highlighted but in the editor it self it only draws a underline. Sometime the underline is just under a single character and sometimes hard to find.

Even though I know the error is in the area I selected using the mini map it's very hard to find. To me error should jump out your eyes. Please see the attached print with 2 one char errors and the mini-map highlight pointed by red arrows.
[image: Sample code with underlined errors on editor and highlighted lines in the mini map]

So I'd like to solve this problem by highlighting the hole line with error in the editor and if possible keep the underline just to point me the exact place the error is (not required - finding the line and seeing which error it is hovering the error makes it easy enough to find the place where the error is).

I've search for this a lot using Google and Stackoverflow. I've found how to changed the color of warning and errors, but not how to changed the underline line to a highlighted one.

Comment: I have noticed this in recent versions of VSCode - the only solution I found was to go back to an older version :(

Comment: @n1k31t4 I believe my VScode is up to date as it is automatic and I always use new versions. The solution below (error lens) is working fine with current versions and make the line with the error very clear. Give it a try if you haven't already.

Comment: I have tried that extension - it does highlight the errors, but it is a workaround. I would prefer the official python extension to highlight the errors correctly, as it used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a try with the Extension of `Error Lens`. It works like this:

[image]

[Official docs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

If you hold your mouse over the error line, `flake8` tells your error.

You can **customize**, **ignore**, or **exclude** errors/files/folders. Or the best thing is you may fix all of them.
For more information, check out [here](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html).

**Sample code (in your case):**

```py
my_dict = {
    "person": [{"id": 1234,  
        "name": "Mert",  # continuation line under-indented for visual indentflake8(E128)
    }]
}

index =0 # missing whitespace around operatorflake8(E225)
```

**Fixed code:**

```py
my_dict = {
    "person": [{
        "id": 1234,
        "name": "Mert",
    }]
}

index = 0
```

#### How to customize flake8?

- Create a .flake8 file.
- Determine your customization like below (sample configuration).

```
[flake8]
ignore = E128,
exclude = .git,__pycache__,docs/source/conf.py,old,build,dist
max-line-length = 160
```

- Enable flake8 linting in .vscode/settings.json (If you don't have a `settings.json` apply instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings))

```
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
```

Comment: I could not understand how you answer is related to my problem. In the first line of you text you state: `If you hold your mouse over the error line, flake8 tells your error.` My problem is not that, my problem is finding the line with error when I have a 4K monitor full of code and the error is a single underlined char as I showed in the print. I just can't see it sometimes. After I find it hovering and getting the error is very simple... Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.